# How to avoid elegantly primitive obsession in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

For a class `Foo` I need an int-like property `SanityCheckPeriod` that allows only values between two limits (say 1 till 7).

What is an elegant way to implement this requirement - maybe with attributes in a declarative manner?
(because I need that pattern multiple times and for expressiveness it would be great to see the limits directly attached to the property.

The idea would be something like this:

```cs
public class Foo
{  
    [RangeAttribute(min: 1, max: 7)]
    public Period SanityCheckPeriod { get; }
    ...
}


public class Period
{
    private int _days;

    private int _max;
    private int _min;

    public int Days
    {
        get => _days;
        private set
        {
            if (_min <= value) 
                throw new ArgumentExcpetion($"Period must be equal or larger than {_min} day(s).");
            if (value <= _max)
                throw new ArgumentExcpetion($"Period must be equal or smaller than {_max} days.");
            _days = value;
        }
    }

    public Period(int days)
    {
        // access the RangeAttribute here
        // how to do? 
        // and set _min and _max
    }
}


[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class RangeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Min { get; }
    public int Max { get; }

    public RangeAttribute(int min, int max)
    {
        Min = min;
        Max = max;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, advice for helping NuGet packages is appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes ?

Comment: How about `public Period SanityCheckPeriod { get; } = new Period(1, 7);`? The `Period` constructor does not have knowledge about the `Foo` class or its members attributes.

Comment: @Matt: this is the other viewpoint direction: from the class where the property with an attribute is used. I don't like to pollute this class with logic and like to keep the logic in a central place outside (e.g. the Attribute or corresponding class where applied)

Comment: @thehennyy: the constructor should be reserved to assign the "instance value", because the consumer is not responsible to set the limits. As a workaround it might be possible to offer a method to set the value (e.g. public Days property). But this a sideeffect then and from the perspective of a DTO the "instance" should be created with its holding data passed by ctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ONLY need exact and wellknown sanity checks, then you could opt for extension methods:

```
public static void SanityCheckPeriod(this int value, int min, int max)
{
    //check sanity
}
```

An elegant way to achieve this in general is with Aspect Oriented Programming which C# doesn't support OOTB. PostSharp is well documented (I'm not affiliated with them) but I don't know if any of their licenses satisfies your needs.

If bringing your own aspect is what you prefer, then you will have to accept that you need to access your object via an "interpreter".

I've seen an example where all objects are accessed via a factory where all objects returned are wrappers which scans the object for custom attributes. So that's a way where BYO aspect oriented code is preferred and where the gritty code is hidden in a single place leaving the rest of the code elegant, then that's a solution as well.

Comment: You are so right. This is a prime example of AOP! PostSharp I have used a while ago.
I will check the license agreement regarding our setup here.

Comment: Hi @MarkoA. Glad to hear. Please mark my answer as useful if you think so. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're not working in the context of a framework that already provides validation conventions (as shown in MVC's [Part 6: Using Data Annotations for Model Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6)).

I'd go for something as the following.

```
public int Days
    {
        get => _days;
        private set { 
            Ensure(1,7);
            _days = value;
        }
    }

private void Ensure(int min, int max, [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName) 
{
  if (_min < value) 
     throw new ArgumentExcpetion($"'{memberName}' must be equal or greater than {min}.");
  if (value < max)
     throw new ArgumentExcpetion($"'{memberName}' must be equal or smaller than {max}.");
}
```

*(Please note I adjusted `<=` and `>=` to match the error messages.)*

Comment: unfortunately no MVC or similar available.
Thanks for your rectification. Indeed that happened because of preparing here. In reality, this is encapsulated and intercepted by the famous SolidStack.Core.Guards library

Answer (score 0):

With @rzmoz hint it was so easy:

1. Install **PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio**
2. Add NuGet packages

   - **PostSharp.Patterns.Model** with the `RangeAttribute`
   - **PostSharp** with the code weaving compiler
3. Apply the `RangeAttribute` to the property

   ```cs
   [Range(1, 7)]
   public int SanityCheckPeriod { get; internal set; }
   ```
4. Compile the stuff and everything works as expected

> Tip: the property cannot be read-only and with `private` setter modifier **R#** complains *Auto-property can be made get-only* and recommends to remove it. But then the weaving will not work. Instead of suppressing this hint I switched to `internal` modifier which will not produce that **R#** hint.